# Loop through Query, assign value on click dynamically ColdFusion

Tags: html, loops, variables, coldfusion, cfml

I have This.

```
<cfquery name="getcities" datasource="local">
    select city, state, ZIP
    from table
    where state = '#stateval#'
    order by city asc
    </cfquery>
    <cfoutput>
      <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>City Names in: #stateval#</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
    <cfloop query="getcities">
      <tr>
        <td>#getcities.cityname#</td>
      </tr>
    </cfloop>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </cfoutput>
```

`stateval` is defined, that is from a select. Looping through the table is fine. I want to have each output be clickable, and when clicked, assign a variable to the name of the `city`. Example: if I loop through where `state` is CA, and I click LA, I want it to assign 'X' to LA. 'X' should be the variable for all. Should be able to have the list up, and click LA, Sacramento, Santa Cruise, and have the variable be set right there to the same of the output. How do I do this??? I've tried to set it to a button, and name the button `#getcities.city#` and name it `#x#` but that wont work unless it's a form. I don't want to submit anything. Just get value dynamically from click accurately inside loop. Then at least for now be able to say `<cfoutput>Here is the city you just clicked: #x#</cfoutput>`

Comment: Look up `<a href>` to create a link. Also look up the purpose of `<cfqueryparam>`

Comment: Depending on what you ultimately want, AJAX and jQuery may be a way to go here. But definitely follow the advice on what `cfqueryparam` does and why you don't want unsanitized variables going into your database.

Comment: Also, if you are going to be working with ColdFusion, http://www.learncfinaweek.com/ is dated, but still a good resource.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `href` with an `onClick` action will do this for you. Here is an example for an alert.

```
<cfquery name="getcities" datasource="local">
    select city, state, ZIP
    from table
    where state = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#stateval#">
    order by city asc
</cfquery>
<cfoutput>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>City Names in: #stateval#</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <cfloop query="getcities">
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="##" onClick="alert('#getcities.cityname#')">#getcities.cityname#</a></td>
                </tr>
            </cfloop>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</cfoutput>
```

Also, look up `cfqueryparam` and why it is important.

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/accessing-and-using-data/accessing-and-retrieving-data/enhancing-security-with-cfqueryparam.html

Comment: It's also a good practice to scope all variables, to avoid unexpected results. For example, `URL.stateVal` or `FORM.stateVal` instead of just `stateVal`.

Comment: @Ageax good call. The only reason I didn’t include it in my answer was because I wasn’t sure which scope he was using.

Comment: Neither was I :) Not really sure what their goal is here. I suspect they really need javascript, but hard to say without more info from the asker.

Comment: @ageax I'm displaying a list of cities in a div, which is sorting by state. The state value is coming from a dropdown. It changes when I click it just fine. Every state has a different amount of cities. I want to be able to click on any city after I load the state, and assign a variable. I will then take this value and pass it via url to another page where a query by state AND City appears in another div. This display specific information about the place that has been selected. That's the goal.

Comment: If you just want to create hyperlinks to another page, you don't need a new variable. Just use the query column inside the loop to create a hyperlink. Similar to the answer above, but the hyperlink would look more like this `<a href="anotherPage.cfm?state=#EncodeForURL(stateVal)#&cityname=#EncodeForURL(CityName)#">#EncodeForHTML(CityName)#</a>`. When a user clicks one of the cityname links, it will redirect to "anotherPage.cfm" (and pass the state and cityname).

Answer (score -1):

I populated the loop results into a div, then used jquery to read the value of the div and pass it as a variable via URL. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Including some code would be helpful to the next person with the same issue. Also, why do you need jQuery to pass a parameter in a URL?

Comment: To do it without refreshing the page

Comment: *Generating* a hyperlink doesn't require a page refresh. So I suspect you mean something else, like displaying new content via ajax without refreshing the page.